# D3.js pie chart to show the percentage of sales in each quarter

Tags: d3.js, pie-chart

Using d3.js I want to make a chart showing each item as pie chart displaying the quarterly sale of tickets for different programs
[image]

here is the sample picture of chart I want to make,each segment in the chart represents ticket for a program and its percentage of sales in each quarter. Now using this link [enter link description here](http://dimplejs.org/examples_viewer.html?id=pie_vertical_grouped)

I have made a graph but which is not exactly the one I needed.Is there any charts available in d3.js to show a graph as I mentioned in the picture or we need to customize it to get a graph like that.

Comment: There is absolutely **no** chart available in D3. D3 is just a collection of methods​ fit manipulating the DOM. I'm voting to close this question as off topic.

Comment: ok @GerardoFurtado using this d3.js will it possible to create a DOM object  that look like in the image I was uploaded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any charts available in d3.js to show a graph as I mentioned
>   in the picture or we need to customize it to get a graph like that?

No there isn't a ready made solution, d3 as the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47215893/d3-js-pie-chart-to-show-the-percentage-of-sales-in-each-quarter#comment81383058_47215893) on the question notes is a collection of methods for manipulating the DOM, this allows a great deal of flexibility in creating custom visualizations (users aren't as limited as with many ready-made solutions that only allow defined modifications). Consequently, yes, you can make a chart like that in d3 taking elements and ideas from both scatter plot and pie chart implementations with d3 to make your chart.

This answer shows one approach that could be used in creating such a graph. Ideally it can provide ideas in crafting your own visualization that meets your need.

First, you need a mechanism to make variable sized pie charts and to place them - arguably this is the hardest part (after that you just have a scatter plot that's easier to manipulate). This requires some thought as to data structure, I've used a structure such as:

```
var data = [
  {x:100,y:100,radius:20,slices:[1,5]},
  {x:150,y:180,radius:10,slices:[1,2,3,4]},
```

You could add other properties as needed, all that this does is specify an x and y coordinate for the pie chart center, a radius for the pie chart, and the values of the wedges for each pie chart.

With that, you can append a group element (`g`) to your svg, one for each pie chart (or item in the data array) using a standard enter cycle in d3, positioning the groups as we go:

```
var pies = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .property("radius",function(d) { return d.radius; })
  .attr("transform",function(d) { return "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")"; });
```

Because the data array used to append the wedges themselves will only include the wedge values, we can save the radius property as a property of the group and access that when appending the wedges:

```
pies.selectAll()
  .data(function(d){ return pie(d.slices); })
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d",function(d) { 
      var radius = d3.select(this.parentNode).property("radius"); 
      arc.outerRadius(radius);
      return arc(d) })
  .attr("fill",function(d,i){
           return color[i];      
      });
```

A basic example might look like this:

```js
var data = [
  {x:100,y:100,radius:20,slices:[1,5]},
  {x:150,y:180,radius:10,slices:[1,2,3,4]},
  {x:180,y:130,radius:30,slices:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]},
  {x:50,y:50,radius:15,slices:[5,3]},
  {x:50,y:180,radius:40,slices:[6,3]}
  ]

var width = 500;
var height = 300;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);
  
var arc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(0)
  .outerRadius(50);
   
var pie = d3.pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d) { return d; });
   
var color = d3.schemeCategory10;

// Append a group for each pie chart, it will store the radius of each pie as a property
var pies = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .property("radius",function(d) { return d.radius; })
  .attr("transform",function(d) { return "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")"; });
  
// draw each pie wedge, using the slices property of the data bound to the parent g  
pies.selectAll()
  .data(function(d){ return pie(d.slices); })
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d",function(d) { 
      var radius = d3.select(this.parentNode).property("radius"); 
      arc.outerRadius(radius);
      return arc(d) })
  .attr("fill",function(d,i){
           return color[i];      
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to set each circle to have it's own color scheme, a few options might be available. If every pie has only two colors, you could assign a fill to the parent group and use the wedge increment to set transparency, creating lighter wedges such as in your image:

```js
var data = [
  {x:100,y:100,radius:20,slices:[1,5]},
  {x:150,y:180,radius:10,slices:[1,2]},
  {x:180,y:130,radius:30,slices:[1,7]},
  {x:50,y:50,radius:15,slices:[5,3]}
  ]

var width = 500;
var height = 300;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);
  
var arc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(0)
  .outerRadius(50);
   
var pie = d3.pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d) { return d; });
   
var color = ["steelblue","orange","pink","crimson"]

// Append a group for each pie chart, it will store the radius of each pie as a property
var pies = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .property("radius",function(d) { return d.radius; })
  .attr("fill",function(d,i) { return color[i] })
  .attr("transform",function(d) { return "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")"; });
  
// draw each pie wedge, using the slices property of the data bound to the parent g  
pies.selectAll()
  .data(function(d){ return pie(d.slices); })
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d",function(d) { 
      var radius = d3.select(this.parentNode).property("radius"); 
      arc.outerRadius(radius);
      return arc(d) })
  .attr("opacity",function(d,i){
           return 1-i*0.2;      
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Other options are available, such as storing a local variable, storing the color as a property as we did for radius, or modifying our data structure to include a color for each wedge:

```js
var data = [
  {x:100,y:100,radius:20,
      slices:[{value:1,color:"steelblue"},{value:5,color:"lightblue"} ]},
      
  {x:150,y:180,radius:10,
       slices:[{value:1,color:"crimson"},{value:2,color:"pink"}]},
        
  {x:180,y:130,radius:30,
       slices:[{value:1,color:"lawngreen"},{value:7,color:"darkgreen"}]}
  ]

var width = 500;
var height = 300;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);
  
var arc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(0)
  .outerRadius(50);
   
var pie = d3.pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d) { return d.value; });

// Append a group for each pie chart, it will store the radius of each pie as a property
var pies = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .property("radius",function(d) { return d.radius; })
  .attr("transform",function(d) { return "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")"; });
  
// draw each pie wedge, using the slices property of the data bound to the parent g  
pies.selectAll()
  .data(function(d){ return pie(d.slices); })
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d",function(d) { 
      var radius = d3.select(this.parentNode).property("radius"); 
      arc.outerRadius(radius);
      return arc(d) })
      // remember that d3.pie creates it's own data array, thus using d.data.property:
   .attr("fill",function(d){ return d.data.color; })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Now we can adapt and implement characteristics of a scatter plot such as scales and axes. This would be the same for any other scatter plot essentially, we would scale the max and min (or a defined range) for the x and y scales, and add the axes. Altogether, that might look something like:

```js
var data = [
  {x:100,y:100,radius:10,slices:[1,5]},
  {x:150,y:180,radius:10,slices:[1,2,3,4]},
  {x:180,y:110,radius:30,slices:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]},
  {x:50,y:100,radius:15,slices:[5,3]},
  {x:50,y:180,radius:40,slices:[6,3]}
  ]

var width = 500;
var height = 300;
var margin = {left:30,right:10,top:30,bottom:30}

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0,width-margin.left-margin.right])
  .domain([0,d3.max(data,function(d) { return d.x + 20 }) ]);
  
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height-margin.top-margin.bottom,0])
  .domain([0,d3.max(data,function(d) { return d.y + 20}) ]);
  

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("height", height);
  
var g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left+","+margin.top+")")
  
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
  
g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,"+(height-margin.bottom-margin.top)+")")
    .call(xAxis);
    
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
  
g.append("g")
    .call(yAxis);

var arc = d3.arc()
   .innerRadius(0)
   .outerRadius(50);
   
var pie = d3.pie()
   .sort(null)
   .value(function(d) { return d; });
   
var color = d3.schemeCategory10;

var pies = g.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .property("radius",function(d) { return d.radius; })
  .attr("transform",function(d) { return "translate("+xScale(d.x)+","+yScale(d.y)+")"; });
  
  
pies.selectAll()
  .data(function(d){ return pie(d.slices); })
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d",function(d) { 
      var radius = d3.select(this.parentNode).property("radius"); 
      arc.outerRadius(radius);
      return arc(d) })
  .attr("fill",function(d,i){
           return color[i];      
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Adding grid lines, legends, mouse over functionality, and other features should be relatively straightforward now - look at scatterplot examples with d3 to see how these and other features might be implemented, modifying a scatterplot of cirlces is about the same as modifying a scatterplot of pie charts.

Comment: That's a really good answer. However, I have to be honest: as a D3 programmer (which is my only source of income), I find this kind of question unfair and disrespectful, and I wish nobody answer it, I wish it was just closed. I love helping fellow programmers here at S.O., but this is simply doing someone else's (whole!) job. I didn't downvote your answer, but I won't upvote it. I hope you understand my point here.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, I understand your point, I originally wasn't going to answer either given the broad nature of the question. Ultimately I figured the solution I proposed wasn't difficult to come by and not particularly novel (there are geographic examples of this for instance). Though uncertainty about that conclusion is probably why I submitted an answer after sitting on the fence for an hour with a typed answer in the box.

Answer (score 0):

From the sample provided by @Andrew Reid I have made it , the sample code for reference is posted here

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <script>
        var data = [

            {x: 170, y: 160, radius: 20, slices: [3, 4]},
            {x: 180, y: 40, radius: 30, slices: [ 6, 7]},
            {x: 50, y: 80, radius: 20, slices: [5, 3]},
            {x: 50, y: 180, radius: 40, slices: [6, 3]}
        ]

        var width = 500;
        var height = 300;
        var margin = {left: 30, right: 10, top: 30, bottom: 30}

        var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                .range([0, width - margin.left - margin.right])
                .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
                        return d.x + 20
                    })]);

        var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                .range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0])
                .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
                        return d.y + 20
                    })]);
        xMid=d3.max(xScale.domain())/2;
        yMid=d3.max(yScale.domain())/2;
        console.log(xMid,yMid)


        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height);

        var g = svg.append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

        var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

        g.append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - margin.bottom - margin.top) + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

        var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

        g.append("g")
                .call(yAxis);
        var lineX= g.append("line")
      .attr("x1", 0)
      .attr("x2", 500)
      .attr("y1", yMid+20)
      .attr("y2", yMid+20)
      .attr("stroke-width", 1)
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr("stroke-dasharray", "7,7");
        var liney= g.append("line")
      .attr("x1", xMid+130)
      .attr("x2", xMid+130)
      .attr("y1", -10)
      .attr("y2", 245)
      .attr("stroke-width", 1)
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr("stroke-dasharray", "7,7");

        var arc = d3.arc()
                .innerRadius(0)
                .outerRadius(50);

        var pie = d3.pie()
                .sort(null)
                .value(function (d) {
                    return d;
                });

        var colors = d3.schemeCategory20;
        var color = ["steelblue","orange","green","red"]
        var pies = g.selectAll(null)
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .property("radius", function (d) {
                    return d.radius;
                })
                .attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + xScale(d.x) + "," + yScale(d.y) + ")";
                })
                .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
                    return color[i];
                });

        pies.selectAll()
                .data(function (d) {
                    return pie(d.slices);
                })
                .enter()
                .append("path")
                .attr("d", function (d) {
                    var radius = d3.select(this.parentNode).property("radius");
                    arc.outerRadius(radius);
                    return arc(d)
                })
                .attr("opacity",function(d,i){ return 1-i*0.7; });
    </script>
</body>
```