# Issues with animating multiple pie charts

Tags: d3.js

Hi StackOverflow Community,

I'm trying to animate multiple pies (inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47215893/d3-js-pie-chart-to-show-the-percentage-of-sales-in-each-quarter#comment81383058_47215893)) based on the dropdown value. However, am facing these issues with the pies whenever the dropdown value changes:

1. the existing pies do not update (reposition, resize or re-slice).
2. the new pie (on year 2004) does not enter nor exit smoothly.

[image]

I want to understand what it is that I've missed to include. Does anyone know of any way to solve the above challenges?
[Here](https://observablehq.com/d/c34918057b66a629) is the notebook that I've been working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an update/exit/enter selection for the groups, then another update/exit/enter selection for the paths.

In short, this is how the groups' selections looks like:

```
let pies = g.selectAll("g.pie_ts")
  .data(data);

pies
  .exit()
  // .transition(transition_duration)
  .remove();

pies = pies
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "pie_ts")
  .property("inner_radius", function(_d) {
    return 0.3 * resize_radius(_d.total_slice);
  })
  .property("outer_radius", function(_d) {
    return resize_radius(_d.total_slice);
  })
  .property("x_value", function(_d) {
    return _d[parameter_x];
  })
  .property("y_value", function(_d) {
    return _d[parameter_y];
  })
  .merge(pies);
```

And this is the paths' selections:

```
let piesArc = pies.selectAll(".pie_ts_slice")
  .data(d => {
    let array = pie([d.total_slice_disposal, d.total_slice_diverted]);
    return array;
  })

piesArc.exit().remove();

piesArc = piesArc.enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("class", "pie_ts_slice")
  .merge(piesArc)
  .attr("transform", function(_d) {
    let x_value = d3.select(this.parentNode).property("x_value");
    let y_value = d3.select(this.parentNode).property("y_value");
    return `translate(${x_scale(x_value)}, ${y_scale(y_value)})`;
  })
  .attr("d", function(_d) {
    let inner_radius = d3.select(this.parentNode).property("inner_radius");
    let outer_radius = d3.select(this.parentNode).property("outer_radius");
    arc
      .innerRadius(inner_radius)
      .outerRadius(outer_radius);
    return arc(_d)
  })
  .attr("fill", function(_d, _i) {
    return color[_i];
  });
```

Comment: It works! Didn't realize that we need to apply merge() on both group and path level. Really appreciate for your help in this (you have saved many weeks of troubleshooting). I have question on the group level: what is the difference between 'pies.enter()' and 'pies = pies.enter()'?

Comment: The second one changes the pies selection for a merge between update and enter selections.